# How to configure a Parse coded app to run on Firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, parse-server

I have an Ionic app which is configured in parse.com backend. How can I change it to work with Firebase backend or is there any alternative for parse.com backend? I tried back4app.com but it can't read my cloud code.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is totally different from Parse.com so if you want to move to firebase you will need to refactor all your client business logic which interact with Parse.com services. A very good alternative is to use [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) which is the Parse.com open source. parse-server can be deployed to any cloud which support NodeJS runtime.

**Please note** if you decided to go with parse-server or with back4app you need to do some modifications to your cloud code and your client side code. The best is to follow the documentation which available under the parse-server github page that i mentioned above. Another good resource is [this one](https://parseplatform.github.io/) which collect all the stuff related to parse-server and how to use parse-server in development or production